# MenuItem appended to PopupMenu is not showing bitmap with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

With Python 2.7 on Linux.

I'm creating MenuItem objects from a list of strings. I am setting the bitmap using `wx.MenuItem.SetBitmap()`, but the images are not showing on the popup menu.

This is my method on creating the PopupMenu:

```
    def CreatePopupMenu(self, list):
          self.menu = wxMenu()
          i = 0
          substring = self.GetLastWord()
          for tableName in list:
                if tableName.startswith(substring):
                item = wx.MenuItem(self.menu, i, tableName)
                item.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('a.png'))
                self.menu.AppendItem(item)
                i += 1
                pos = self._Editor.PointFromPosition(self._Editor.GetCurrentPos())
                pos.x += self._Editor.GetFont().GetPixelSize().width
                pos.y += self._Editor.GetFont().GetPixelSize().height
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnPopupItemSelected, item)

          if self.menu.GetMenuItemCount() > 0:
                #menuItem = self.menu.FindItemById(0)
                self.PopupMenu(self.menu, pos)
          self.menu.Destroy()
```

Comment: this code can not work. look at the use of nomeTabela and tableName

Comment: Corrected the code. But besides that, i can only think of its a bug..

Comment: still there are bugs: wxMenu would fail. why don't you copy/paste from the functional code ?

Comment: Thanks joaquim, but actually my code worked. The problem was exactly that one from my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind awkward, but I found the answer to my own question. The problem is not language specific but a matter of gnome' settings.

Apparently Gnome defaults to not enabling icons on menu items...

Found it [here](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wx-MenuItem-icon-is-missing-td4555866.html#a4562941).

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Check this adapted code:

```
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)
    self.CreatePopupMenu(['mOpen', 'mClose', 'mFile'])
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    menuBar.Append(self.menu, 'menu')
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

def CreatePopupMenu(self, list):
    self.menu = wx.Menu()
    i = 0
    #substring = self.GetLastWord()
    substring = 'm'
    for tableName in list:
        if tableName.startswith(substring):
            item = wx.MenuItem(self.menu, i, tableName)
            item.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('zimages/gato.png'))
            self.menu.AppendItem(item)
```

[image]